# Adobe air full screen in ios

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have created a basic flash module using intellij idea. When i run the app in android which shows the content in full screen but when i run the same app in ios there is some blank black space on top and bottom of the screen.

This is the screen shot of view in android

[image]

This is the view in ios

[image]

Here is my ios description xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
```

```
<id>Main</id>
<filename>Main</filename>
<name>Main</name>
<versionNumber>0.0.1</versionNumber>
<versionLabel>0.01</versionLabel>



<initialWindow>
    <content>main.swf</content>
    <aspectRatio>any</aspectRatio>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <renderMode>auto</renderMode>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <softKeyboardBehavior>pan</softKeyboardBehavior>
</initialWindow>

<!--<icon>-->
    <!--<image16x16>16x16.png</image16x16>-->
    <!--<image32x32>32x32.png</image32x32>-->
    <!--<image48x48>48x48.png</image48x48>-->
    <!--<image57x57>57x57.png</image57x57>-->
    <!--<image72x72>72x72.png</image72x72>-->
    <!--<image76x76>76x76.png</image76x76>-->
    <!--<image120x120>120x120.png</image120x120>-->
    <!--<image128x128>128x128.png</image128x128>-->
    <!--<image152x152>152x152.png</image152x152>-->
<!--</icon>-->

<supportedProfiles>mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>



<iPhone>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    <assetsCar>Assets.car</assetsCar>
    <InfoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[

        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <!-- iPhone and iPod touch devices -->
            <string>1</string>
            <!-- iPad devices -->
            <string>2</string>
        </array>


        ]]>
    </InfoAdditions>

</iPhone>
```

Now i would like to know how can i make the ui in ios also same as in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the launch images for iOS. This is why you get the black bars. If you add them for the device you are testing, it will go full screen. In order to add them you can go to [this link](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/launch-images-on-ios-with-adobe-air.html), find the appropriate dimension, and then add a png file in your src file.

Make sure to include these files during export.

You can also use [this tool](https://www.appicon.build/) to autogenerate all the files needed